# Why doesn't my variable behave as an IEnumerable?

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, azure-storage

I installed the Windows Azure Storage Client for Windows Phone from Nuget Packages.
I want list the name of containers.
Why don't behave my "st" variable as a IEnumerable?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have imported the [`System.Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx) namespace (e.g. like below)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```